# Change cell color in a dynamic browse

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, 4gl

I have tried to color specific cell in a dynamic browse 4GL.
However, I was unable to do this for multiple rows.
The following code only works for the first row.
[Current browse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8PMU.png)

How do I iterate through multiple rows so that I can color the cell ?

```
/* DEFINITIONS */
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttField
FIELD hHandle AS HANDLE
FIELD cField AS CHARACTER.

/* Before Open Query e.g. procedure initialiseBrowse */
DEF VAR hTemp AS HANDLE.

hTemp = BROWSE {&BROWSE-NAME}:FIRST-COLUMN.

REPEAT:
  CREATE ttField.
  ASSIGN
    ttField.cField = hTemp:NAME
    ttField.hHandle = hTemp.

  IF VALID-HANDLE(hTemp:NEXT-COLUMN) THEN
  hTemp = hTemp:NEXT-COLUMN.
  ELSE LEAVE.
END.


/* Row display - How to do this ?? */
IF /* user clause */ TRUE THEN
DO:
  FOR EACH ttField WHERE LOOKUP("FIELD-LIST", cField) > 0:
    ASSIGN ttField.hHandle:BGCOLOR = 12.
  END.
END.
```

Answer (score 4):

This k-base article shows a complete sample for using the ROW-DiSPLAY trigger: https://community.progress.com/s/article/21627

So basically you add

```
ON ROW-DISPLAY OF {&BROWSE-NAME} IN {&FRAME-NAME} DO:
  /* Row display - How to do this ?? */
  IF /* user clause */ TRUE THEN
  DO:
    FOR EACH ttField WHERE LOOKUP("FIELD-LIST", cField) > 0:
      ASSIGN ttField.hHandle:BGCOLOR = 12.
    END.
  END.
END.
```